# Problem with MDI form in c#

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

When I called show() of MDI child from its parent for the first, got the following error...

Method: CheckReleased Line: 0 Column: 0
[Exception]: Window handle already exists.

What is the cause for this error and how to overcome it?

Call to show() of the same child for the second time is not giving any exception. why it is failing for first time only?

Iam using Dotnet 3.5 framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason could be, Are you trying to show some child controls before the Form shows up.?

This error normally show off, if you try to make some child control visible (in the form), before the window get created. Because all the child controls in the forms needs it's parent handle.

Comment: yes, thank you. The above issue is resolved after adding the mdi child while the parent form is getting loaded. Initially I tried to add mdi child in the constructor of the parent form .

Comment: if your issue is resolved due to above answer you should vote up above answer. According to SO FAQs you should up-vote helpful answers so that visitors will know which answer was correct and helpful. +1

Answer (score -2):

Append a MenuStrip to an MDI Parent Window (Windows Forms) c# (or) mdi child menu in wpf

http://keranservices.blogspot.in/2014/02/append-menustrip-to-mdi-parent-window.html

Comment: kindly provide the explanatory answer in the post itself, instead of pointing to links. Links can break anytime..